# $\vert \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}} \vert = \vert \mathbb{R} \vert $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I want to show that $\vert \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{Z}} \vert = \vert \mathbb{R} \vert $.
Do the real numbers and the countable product of real numbers have the same cardinality?

Comment: Yes. $|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}| = |\mathbb{R}|^{|\mathbb{Z}|} = (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0^2} = 2^{\aleph_0} = |\mathbb{R}|$.